# How to remove index.php from CodeIgniter3 install in subdirectory with Wordpress on root?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So the title of the question was a little difficult to come up with. Here's the deal, the CI3 install is like this: www.mydomain.com.au/apps/TGPS where TGPS is the CI application. Additionally, on the root of the web folder there is a Wordpress install. My question is, what is the .htaccess setup that I need to compress the URLs from:
www.domain.com/apps/TGPS/index.php/controller/function
to this:
www.domain.com/apps/TGPS/controller/function

At present I have this:

[image]

The top level .htacess is this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^/apps($|/) - [L] 
# END WordPress
```

The .htaccess in TGPS is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

and the .htaccess in application is the standard one.

Seems everything I try either breaks Wordpress, CodeIgniter or has no effect. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please make sure that inside your /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf or please search where is your httpd.conf file is and change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

Comment: I made the change, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I made the change, it didn't actually change anything though. I just assumed it was part of the process.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
Now try this one

Comment: copy entire code above to your .htaccess

Comment: I coped the code into the .htaccess in the folder TGPS, no joy. Still can't hit www.domain.com.au/apps/TGPS/controller/function without adding index.php.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, you're missing a rewrite base:

```
RewriteBase /apps/TGPS/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow code

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]
```

Then the www to non-www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What level does that .htaccess go on in the directory?

Comment: Write after `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`
    `RewriteEngine On`   in htaccess public directory .